# Angular js Advanced Search

Tags: angularjs, search

I want to do an advance search in my angular-laravel classified site. We have different field to search. These fields are dynamically created from admin side.From each field we have multiple inputs to search. From the same field we have to perform OR functions and from the different field we have to perform AND functions.how to do it in angularjs? Please help me.
[image]

I am trying to do the search by fetching all the data and filetr using angular js filter function.But i didnt get the result which satisfied all the conditions.Is it possible to do this search function without send http request all the time?

Comment: Have you write any code for this?

Comment: just create multi dimension array of search like `$scope.search.fuel`, `$scope.search.mpg` so that when user click on search button you need only pass to `$scope.search` variable to http request